# Django Foreign Keys Breaking with Multi-Table Inheritance

Tags: django, django-models

The following code works as I expect it to:

```
class General(Model):
    pass

class Captain(Model):
    general = ForeignKey('General',related_name='captains')
```

I can create a general, add captains, and doing "general.captains" works as expected.

But when both these classes inherit from a base class that might have extra info, disaster strikes.

```
class Officer(Model):
    pass

class General(Officer):
    pass

class Captain(Officer):
    general = ForeignKey('General',related_name='captains')


>>> g = General()
>>> g.captains
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line
391, in __get__
    self.related.model._default_manager.__class__)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line
469, in create_manager
    getattr(instance, attname)}
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line
301, in __get__
    raise self.field.rel.to.DoesNotExist
DoesNotExist
```

Any idea what might be happening here, and how I could fix it?

Comment: I faced a similar issue, I am inclined to believe it is a known issue. "Avoid 2nd level inhertance" is the silver bullet.

Comment: Did you get the problem fixed?

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you define your `Officer` model explicitly as [abstract](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance)

```
class Meta:
    abstract = True
```

So as a test i slightly modified your base class:

```
class Officer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    class Meta:
       abstract = True
```

And the following works:

```
>>> General(name='Warfield').save()
>>> G = General.objects.all()[0]
>>> Captain(name='Picard', general=G).save()
>>> C = Captain.objects.all()[0]    
>>> C.general.name
u'Warfield'
>>> G.captains.all()[0].name
u'Picard'
```